# Logarithmic equations with different bases

Tags: logarithms

I had problems understanding how to solve 
$$
6^{-\log_{6}^2}
$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you tell me if the expression that you wrote is $\displaystyle 6^{-\log_6 2}$?

Comment: I am guessing that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let,
$$ 
x=6^{-\log_6 2}
$$
Thus,
$$
\log_6 x =-\log_6 2 = \log_6 2^{-1} = \log_6 \frac{1}{2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad x=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}e^x = y \rightarrow ln(y) = x
\\ \rightarrow e^{ln(y)}= e^x=y 
\\ thus:
\\ 6^{-log_6(2)}=({6^{log_6{2}}})^{-1}=(2)^{-1}=1/2
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
6^{-\log_6(2)} &= \frac{1}{6^{\log_6(2)}} \quad \text{by definition of negative power}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{since $6^x$ and $\log_6(x)$ are inverses}
\end{align}
$$